# How to schedule all the cron jobs to run after truncate the cron table?

Tags: magento2, database, cron, crontab

I truncate my CRON job schedules using this command below:

```
TRUNCATE cron_schedule;
```

I wait some time but I'm not seeing the schedules populating the table again as you can see here.

[image: Magento 2 last executed cron jobs empty]

How can I reschedule the cron jobs again in order to show on this table?

Comment: is it usually safe to truncate cron_schedule? Wouldn't we miss any job?

Comment: The jobs are recreated using the solution below @MohammedJoraid

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Magerun2** to schedule all the native cron jobs again using these commands below:

```
n98-magerun2 cron:run
```

or

```
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule aggregate_sales_report_coupons_data
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule aggregate_sales_report_invoiced_data
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule aggregate_sales_report_order_data
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule aggregate_sales_report_refunded_data
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule aggregate_sales_report_shipment_data
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule aggregate_sales_report_tax_data
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule analytics_collect_data
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule analytics_subscribe
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule analytics_update
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule backend_clean_cache
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule captcha_delete_expired_images
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule captcha_delete_old_attempts
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule catalog_index_refresh_price
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule catalog_product_alert
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule catalog_product_attribute_value_synchronize
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule catalog_product_flat_indexer_store_cleanup
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule catalogrule_apply_all
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule currency_rates_update
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule expired_tokens_cleanup
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule get_amazon_authorization_updates
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule get_amazon_capture_updates
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule indexer_clean_all_changelogs
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule indexer_reindex_all_invalid
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule indexer_update_all_views
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule magento_newrelicreporting_cron
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule newsletter_send_all
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule paypal_fetch_settlement_reports
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule persistent_clear_expired
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_clean_orders
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_clean_quotes
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_grid_order_async_insert
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_send_order_emails
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_send_order_invoice_emails
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sales_send_order_shipment_emails
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule security_clean_admin_expired_sessions
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule security_clean_password_reset_request_event_records
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule sitemap_generate
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule system_backup
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:schedule visitor_clean
```